# Third Party Cookie Blocking issue using ajax http calls in 2021 (ITP restrictions)?

Tags: ajax, cookies, cross-domain-policy

Faced with issue, when browser can't send cookies to different domain during ajax call, even

**SameSite** cookie attribute set to `none`, **secure** attribute set to **true**

**withCredentials** ajax param set to `true`

So, looks like we faced with **Third-Party Cookie Blocking** policy, that already enabled by default in Safari and will be enabled in nearest future in Chrome/FF/etc.

In case of Safari it called **Intelligent Tracking Prevention (ITP)**

You can find few options how to resolve it here : https://webkit.org/blog/10218/full-third-party-cookie-blocking-and-more/

But... seems like except Oauth redirects and iframe options, there are no any cross-browser ways **for Ajax call**?

Maybe someone has any solutions or workarounds, guys?

Comment: +1 on this. I've been trying for hours to get an ajax request to go through cross domain with cookies on chrome 88 to no avail